# Python setuptools - maintain text file reference in a subfolder?

Tags: python, installation, setuptools, setup-project

I have an application that when not passed a command line argument, defaults to a default file found in a folder `./wordlists`. This works fine out of the host folder but once I run `setup.py install` the application loses the reference, and I'm unsure why.

This is my current setup.py:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup


def dependencies(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        return f.read().splitlines()

with open("README.md") as f:
    setup(
        name="<redacted>",
        license="<redacted>",
        description="<redacted>",
        long_description=f.read(),
        author="<redacted>",
        author_email="<redacted>",
        url="<redacted>",
        packages=find_packages(exclude=('tests')),
        package_data={'wordlists': ['*.txt', './wordlists/*.txt']},
        scripts=['<redacted>'],
        install_requires=dependencies('requirements.txt'),
        tests_require=dependencies('test-requirements.txt'),
        include_package_data=True)
```

As stated, I can run the application in my directory using:

```
python ./VHostScan.py -t <target>
```

And it will then default to the wordlist:

```
./wordlists/virtual-host-scanning.txt
```

However after using `./setup.py install` and then attempting to run the application it loses the link to the wordlist.

This is what I've tried to add into my setup.py, but I'm guessing I need to either make changes here, or where the wordlist reference is:

```
package_data={'wordlists': ['*.txt', './wordlists/*.txt']},
```

This is how I reference the default wordlist file:

```
DEFAULT_WORDLIST_FILE = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),
    'wordlists',
    'virtual-host-scanning.txt'
)
```

And the full codebase is available here, if needed: https://github.com/codingo/VHostScan/

Comment: You don't have `setup.py` at Github. Please add.

Comment: @phd it's not in master atm, but it is in a branch awaiting pr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems in you `setup.py` and your package:

1. You have a module `VHostScan.py` at the top but is not listed in `setup.py`; because of that it's not installed and not included in a binary distribution(s).

To fix: add `py_modules=['VHostScan.py']`.

2. The directory `wordlists` is not a Python package hence `find_packages` doesn't find it and hence `package_data` files aren't included.

I see 2 ways to fix it:

a) Make the directory `wordlists` a Python package (add an empty `__init__.py`);

b) Apply `package_data` to the `lib` package:

```
package_data={'lib': ['../wordlists/*.txt']},
```